# How i run my AIR application instance that is already running in the system tray?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have an AIR Application that is running already and minimize in the system tray.
Now if user try to start application from desktop icon or from start menu the application which is dock/minimize in system tray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this blogpost:
[All AIR Applications Are Single-Instance](http://noclevercode.santacruzsoftware.com/blog/archives/500)